# Limit Stylesheet to one tag and descendents

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

I want to use twitter bootstrap for some site I am working on.  This site requires a pre-set template to be used for certain parts of the page.

If I include the twitter bootstrap stylesheet it messes up the original template.

I want to include the external bootstrap.cc stylesheet but make it work only on tags which are a descendent of class="mycontent"

```
<html>
<link href="original stylsheet.css">
<link href="bootstrap.css">
...
...
<div class="header">
original stlesheet to be used here
</div>
<div class="mycontent">
bootstrap css to work for all descendents of my content
</div>
```

I know one way is to edit the css and add .mycontent before each and every tag. But I was wondering if there was a smarter solution

Comment: Include bootstrap before the original stylesheet, so your styles override those in bootstrap.

Comment: that works for the most part.... BUT it fails if there is a modification in bootstrap which isnt present in my original stylesheet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Scoped CSS

If `scope` attribute is present, then `<style>` applies only to its parent element.

```
<div>
  <style scoped>
  /* your css here */
  <style>
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

It lacks of browser support, but there is a polyfill: [jQuery Scoped CSS plugin](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin).

Additional reading: [Saving the Day with Scoped CSS](http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/).

---

Current browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped

Answer (score -1):

As you i can see your code :

```
<html>
<link rel="original stylsheet.css">
<link rel="bootstrap.css">
...
...
<div class="header">
original stlesheet to be used here
</div>
<div class="mycontent">
bootstrap css to work for all descendents of my content
</div>
```

you are using the wrong path.
you should try `<link href="bootstrap.css">`
I hope your problem will be solve with this

Comment: Ok that was a typo here... my question still stands... i want the extrenal stylesheet to affect only elements under mycontent