# Applying CSS styles to all elements inside a DIV

Tags: html, css

I would like to apply a CSS file to a concrete DIV in my page. This is the page structure:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
...
<body>
   <div id="pagina-page" data-role="page">
   ...
   <div id="applyCSS">
      (all the elements here must follow a concrete CSS rules)
   </div>
   ...
</body>
```

I tried to apply the rules of the CSS file editing it like this (the CSS file is so large):

```css
#applyCSS * {     (For all the elements inside "applyCSS" DIV:)
    .ui-bar-a {
       ...
       ...
    }
    .ui-bar-a .ui-link-inherit {
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But that solution doesn't work. So, how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110708/limit-stylesheet-to-one-tag-and-descendents/12553605#12553605

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could try:

```css
#applyCSS .ui-bar-a {property:value}
#applyCSS .ui-bar-a .ui-link-inherit {property:value}
```

Etc, etc... Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, but the file is too large, so I trying to find other method to do the same.

Comment: Not the perfect solution, but with Notepad++ you can edit vertically any number of rows and apply this :p

Answer (score 160):

```css
#applyCSS > * {
  /* Your style */
}
```

Check this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/qNCe2/)

It will style all children and grandchildren, but will exclude loosely flying text in the div itself and only target wrapped (by tags) content.

Comment: Brilliant, top-notch response. Should be the answer to this question

Comment: this only targets direct children, so it should be: #applyCSS  *

Comment: @yennefer even  `#applyCSS *` did not work for me for grandchildren. @Arkana's answer worked for me

Comment: #applyCSS > h3 {
  color: red;
}
This doesnt work when i want to color only h3 tags @Nisse Engström

Answer (score 28):

```
.yourWrapperClass * {
 /* your styles for ALL */
}
```

This code will apply styles all elements inside .yourWrapperClass.

Comment: How do I override this for specific tags? I tried  `.yourWrapperClass a { /*style for links*/}` But still got the * css applied.  Basically I want to define default css and if needed, want to override for specific tags.

Answer (score 10):

I do not understand why it does not work for you, it works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/wcm1soma/1/

The HTML

```
<div id="pagina-page" data-role="page">
    <div id="applyCSS">
    <!--all the elements here must follow a concrete CSS rules-->
        <a class="ui-bar-a">This "a" element text should be red
            <span class="ui-link-inherit">This span text in "a" element should be red too</span>
        </a>      
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```css
#applyCSS * {color:red;display:block;margin:20px;}
```

Maybe you have some special rules that you did not share with us...

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for a shortcut for writing out all of your selectors, then a CSS Preprocessor (Sass, LESS, Stylus, etc.) can do what you're looking for.  However, the generated styles must be valid CSS.

Sass:

```css
#applyCSS {
    .ui-bar-a {
       color: blue;
    }
    .ui-bar-a .ui-link-inherit {
       color: orange;
    }
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Generated CSS:

```css
#applyCSS {
  background: #CCC;
}

#applyCSS .ui-bar-a {
  color: blue;
}

#applyCSS .ui-bar-a .ui-link-inherit {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Write all class/id CSS as below. `#applyCSS` ID will be parent of all CSS code.

For example you add class `.ui-bar-a` in CSS for applying to your div:

```css
#applyCSS .ui-bar-a  { font-size:11px; } /* This will be your CSS part */
```

Below is your HTML part:

```
<div id="applyCSS">
   <div class="ui-bar-a">testing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this any different than Arkana's answer, which was submitted ~7 minutes earlier?

Answer (score -1):

Alternate solution. Include your external CSS in your HTML file by

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/applyCSS.css"/>
```

inside the applyCSS.css:

```
   #applyCSS {
      /** Your Style**/
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only apply to the element its self and not the contents inside it?