# How to make CSS apply on specific specific elements?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a timeline as the one thats shown [here](https://codepen.io/snookca/pen/ELEdZo). 
In the example the author uses the `<p>` tag in the CSS to display the timeline effect. When I use this code in my code. Every section where I've used a `<p>` tag gets the CSS effect, which I don't want.

So to avoid this I tried to use an ID I gave all of the `<p>` tags where I wanted the effect to show up an ID and I declared the CSS in the CSS file with the ID.

This is what I tried:

```css
#te p {
  border-top: 2px dashed;
  border-color: blue !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
}

#te p:nth-child(even) {
  border-left: 2px dashed;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#te p:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right: 2px dashed;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#te p:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

#te p:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p id="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p id="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p id="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p id="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
</div>
```

But it did not work. The CSS didn't execute. After that I tried what was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901522/applying-css-styles-to-all-elements-inside-a-div) stack overflow question. But that didn't work either.

So how do I apply this CSS to only the few `<p>` tags mentioned here and not any of the other `<p>` tags that exist somewhere else in the code?

Thank you

Comment: Use `class` instead of `id`, ID should be unique for only one element in HTML but the class can use multiple

Comment: First of all, change `id` to `class`, as `id` must be unique. Second, since `te` is already the `p` element, `#te p` should be just `#te`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason you're code was not working was the selectors were not used properly. 
As you can see below, I slightly tweaked your code and it works fine.

Cheers. 
P.S. IDs should be unique. Please use classes when targeting more than one element.

```css
 #te {
  border-top: 2px dashed;
  border-color: blue !important;
  margin:0; padding: 30px;
}



#te:nth-child(even) {
  border-left: 2px dashed;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px; 
  padding-right: 0;
}

#te:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right: 2px dashed;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px; 
  padding-left: 0;
}

#te:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
  border-top-right-radius:0;
  border-top-left-radius:0;
}

#te:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius:0;
  border-bottom-left-radius:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <p id="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
        <p id="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
        <p id="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
        <p id="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
        <p id="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I didnt know that you could use ids like that!

Comment: IDs should be unique, so besides that this code works, using the same ID for multiple elements is a bad practice, and a potential bug source...

Comment: That's true. but even on using "class" the code wouldn't have worked. 
The issue was incorrect usage of CSS selectors.
However, as a suggestion, I can add your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work, because after the ID, there's a space, which will try to select a descendant of the `#te`, that match `p`.

So you have to reverse the order of these selectors, and remove the space, like:

```
p#te
```

And, IDs meant to be unique, so you should use a class instead (you can select it via `.` instead of `#`).

So, your code should look like:

```css
p.te{
  border-top: 2px dashed;
  border-color: blue !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
}

p.te:nth-child(even) {
  border-left: 2px dashed;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-right: 0;
}

p.te:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right: 2px dashed;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

p.te:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

p.te:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p class="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p class="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p class="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p class="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ids in HTML must be unique... use classes instead:

```css
p.te {
  border-top: 2px dashed;
  border-color: blue !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
}

p.te:nth-child(even) {
  border-left: 2px dashed;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-right: 0;
}

p.te:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right: 2px dashed;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

p.te:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

#te p:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p class="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p class="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p class="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
  <p class="te">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, iste iusto quas eligendi corporis id eius corrupti temporibus velit? Molestias harum voluptatibus veritatis explicabo ut velit deserunt, saepe sit commodi?</p>
</div>
```